# Длинный текст в Spinner на Андроиде.

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-spinner

Имеется очень длинный текст, который  в выпадающем списке на андроиде не умещается.

```
  ArrayList<String> List=new ArrayList<String>();
  List.add("длинный текст!");
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>       
  (getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_item, List); 
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_dropdown_item);
```

Можно ли сделать, чтобы этот текст как-то двигался, прокручивался?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще спинер для сего не предназначен. Но можно попробовать **подменить стандартную разметку элементов на свою**, в кою можно пихнуть всё что угодно. Например **TextView** в **ScrollView**. Но не факт, что будет корректно работать.

Можно ещё попробовать просто **TextView** с высотой **wrap_content**

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать библиотеку автоматически уменьшающую размер шрифта - https://github.com/erchenger/SizeAdjustingTextView.

для этого элемента списка создайте свой layout